# How To Save Background Image On Form Close In C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making a desktop app in c# in which when the user selects specific name of background from the menu strip, then the background shall turn to that required background. The problem is that i cannot save the user input, i tried settings but i cannot find "system.drawing.image" in settings so is there any way i can save the user changed background ? No external backgrounds a user is allowed to change, just the ones in the resource folder. Here is my code which shows error that system.drawing.color cannot take place of drawing.image.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace TAC
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(165, 157);
        panel2.Location = new Point(289, 158);
        panel3.Location = new Point(47, 275);
        panel4.Location = new Point(47, 402);
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Settings.Default.FormImage;
    }

    private void bLUEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = TAC.Properties.Resources.tex1;
    }

    private void gREENToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = TAC.Properties.Resources.tex2;
    }

    private void oRANGEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = TAC.Properties.Resources.tex3;
    }

    private void rEDToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = TAC.Properties.Resources.tex4;
    }

    private void pURPLEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = TAC.Properties.Resources.tex5;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.FormImage = this.BackgroundImage;
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Save method to save settings

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you want add an image to settings :

Add new setting with type string and use like this:

Save an image to setting ( when you close form)

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Propertis.Resources.MyImage.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Properties.Settings.Default.BackImg = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And read image from setting and set to background(in form load)

```
string img =  Properties.Settings.Default.BackImg ;
byte[] i = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(i));
```

How add custom settings ?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29130/Windows-Forms-Creating-and-Persisting-Custom-User

Comment: I added the save code you have given here on form closing and added use code on form loading and first, the semicolon given exception error when i try to debug my app and secondly, should i do this method thrice for three different images ? like there is a drop down i have added and from there, user selects image, so when an image is selected, then on form closing, it should be saved and when form reopens, that selected image should be the background.

Comment: Here download [My Project Files](https://app.box.com/s/uujxlu26xgb1o1mvu9w6tavxm0fjfsfj) and edit them please so i can understand what to do.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you said because of English.you can put code in method for reuse: SaveToSetting(Image i) .you can set every image that user has selected to background . Then when you want close , save it to settings.and in form load read from setting

Comment: I couldn't download your project.but I edited my answer.just put everything in where I said

Comment: And as a noob, i didnt understand what you said you please look at the files i set sent you ! and edit them so i can understand ! [DOWNLOAD HERE](https://app.box.com/s/uujxlu26xgb1o1mvu9w6tavxm0fjfsfj)

Comment: OK MAN THANKS ALOT ! :)